# Modifying filename with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this filename 888_325586_657D.84147.abcdefguh.496900888.20201217.042724

I need to rename it to 888.84147.se.123456789.20201217.042724

I need some help.

Comment: You are not new to stackoverflow so you should absolutely know that this post is off topic. Please edit to include what you've tried along with any errors or other pertinent details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Rename-Item` cmdlet. Follow syntax similar to this:

```
Rename-Item -Path "c:\logfiles\daily_file.txt" -NewName "monday_file.txt"
```

Learn more about this cmdlet here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item